# Button Click issue in Webdriverio tool

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I'm trying to learn automation with webdriverio tool using typescript. I am able to launch the browser and hit the URL. But unable to click the button in the initial screen.

Can someone help? Details below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9i5q.png]

front code for the button is

```html
<button rfs-button-primary="" ng-attr-id="{{vm.generateButtonId(button)}}" type="button" ng-click="vm.startIvoConfig()" ng-disabled="vm.nextButtonDisabled" class="ng-binding" id="Bereken_uw_premie">Bereken uw premie</button>
```

I am writing the code as below in webdriverio tool

```javascript
browser.maximizeWindow();
const button = $('#Bereken_uw_premie');
button.waitForDisplayed();
button.click();
```

But the button is not clicked. Any other solution?

Comment: is there any error/exception you are getting ?

Comment: no error message. when i run the script, it invokes the browser and hit the URL.

Comment: Tried in both Chrome and Firefox browsers

Comment: You are saying there are no errors in the WDIO logs? If yes, then can you confirm is the above piece of code is actually executed and can you paste those respective wdio logs. And before all of these, does it works manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use xpath i think that can be work:

```
"//button[@id='Bereken_uw_premie']" or
"//div//button[@id='Bereken_uw_premie']"
```

it can be look like:

```
browser.maximizeWindow();
const xpathButton = "//button[@id='Bereken_uw_premie']";
$(xpathButton).waitForDisplayed();
$(xpathButton).click();
```

If that dont work please check maybe you should wait after click sometimes the application responds to a click for a long time.